# How can i fix this error in expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

i'm using expressjs with jade. I'm trying to do a factorial with an input, but i can't display the answer for example if i input 5 the result is 120, but display a big error. How can i make this?
Please can you help me?
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0nGw.png)

```js
routes/index.js

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
 res.render('index.jade', { title: 'Express' });
});


router.get('/factorial', function(req, res, next) {
 res.render('factorial.jade', { title: 'Factorial' });
});

 

module.exports = router;
```

```css
views/factorial

extends layout

block content
 h1= title
 p Welcome to #{title}
 p Ingrese un numero
 form(method="POST", action="/factorial", name="myForm",onsubmit='return validateForm()')
  input(type='number', name='numero')
  input(type='submit', value='Enviar')
```

```html
<strong>archive app.js</strong>

var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
//agregado
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var engine = require('ejs-mate');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// instruct the app to use the `bodyParser()` middleware for all routes
app.use(bodyParser());

// view engine setup
app.engine('ejs', engine);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');


app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'bower_components')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

app.post('/factorial', function(req, res) {
  var num=req.body.numero;
  dd(num);
  for(var i=1;i<=num;i++)
    i=i*num;
  res.send('/factorial'+i);
});

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

Comment: As a start, try changing `res.send('/factorial'+i);` to `res.send(num);`

Comment: thank you @HeadCode worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
var express = require("express")
var app = express()

function factorial(num) {
  if (num < 0)
    return "INVALID"
  if (num == 1 || num == 0)
    return 1
  else return num * factorial(num - 1)
}

app.get("/factorial/:num", function (req, res) {
  var num = req.params.num;  
  res.status(200).send(""+factorial(num))
})

app.listen(3000)
```

point your browser to http://localhost:300/factorial/4 for example.

Answer (score 0):

I can see at least one mistake:

```
res.send(/factorial + i)
```

isn't in any known way of sending an answer, and probably is the cause of the error . In fact the errro is telling you that you send an invalid result code (45), probably becuase interprets the first char of your response (/) as return code, as yor're not providing the correct response headers

Also, except the ddd(num) call is something magic you algorythm for calculating a factorial isn't correct. Supose you send a 5, (result should be **5*4*3*2*1 =120**). Then

- loop pass it retuns 1
- loop pass it retuns 10
- and exits because i is currently bigger than 5

a numerically working  version could be:

```
app.post('/factorial', function(req, res) {
   var num=req.body.numero;
   dd(num);  // << dont know what it does

  function fact(n) {
    if (n < 2) return n
    else return n*fact(n-1)
  } 
  var result = fact(num)
  ...
});
```

For correctly send the result, you should read the related docs. Too long to answer here